# How do I Debug an ASP.net project on IIS7, if I took the project from a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, windows-7, asp.net

I use mostly Apache and PHP, so I'm very unfamiliar with IIS and .aspx

I have a .aspx file (`myFile.aspx`) I'm debugging, and I would like to see - using localhost - what it will look like on the server (which is Windows 2003, I think) when looked at by a user. I'm using Windows 7 for debugging, but the project lives - and will continue to live - on a Windows 2003 server.

I have IIS up and running, so initially when I went to `http://localhost/`, I could see the IIS logo. I now have the Physical Path pointing to the directory with my ASP project.

The problem is that due to the server mismatches, when I go to the page (`myFile.aspx`) I get a server error because the related configuration data (`web.config`) for the page is invalid (`HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`).

How can I work around this? Are there any good tutorials that cover this matter? Any help appreciated.

Comment: If your OS is Server 2003, you aren't running IIS 7 because IIS is tied to the OS and only became available on Server 2008

Comment: @GregD - My OS is Windows 7 for my personal computer on which I want to debug the file. After I debug the file I want to upload it to a completely separate Windows 2003 Server which serves the file to the WWW. I want to test the file on my personal computer and not the live server.

Comment: Your title says, "Windows 2003 server with IIS7"...that combo does not exist...

Comment: @GregD, the words before that phrase were important too, but I reworded the title to make it - hopefully - more clear.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google or Bing search for this may have helped:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

This has all of the potentially related error messages you are seeing and more importantly tells you exactly what to look at to get it fixed.

Answer (score -2):

what important stuff is in your web.config? I would remove everything except the stuff you need. If your situation is complex, you might want to get your hands on a test server. You could get a virtual machine from godaddy for $30 for a month...

Comment: -1 He already has a Win7 and 2003 box, why would he need a test server?

Comment: Because he doesnt have a test machine with iis 6? The 2003 box is prod right?

Comment: Just because it's prod doesn't mean you can't create another VD to test with... Plus if you can get it to run in IIS7 most likely it will run in IIS6